# Reading a ini file containing italian accented letters using ConfigParser in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Update: the problem is worst then I supposed it was. The first problem is that the ini file may be written by the user, so it may be written in the default encoded format that varies by the language family. So, my program has to manage not only utf-8 but a lot of formats.

Yesterday I solve the problem of italian accente letters in strings, basically the problew was that PyEclipse does not save the source files encoded in utf-8 but using the default encoding of the operative system.
In this case I wrote a ini file and saved it encoded in utf-8, then I am trying to read it using ConfigParser specifying that the file is encoded in utf-8 but anyway, when I read the file I have this error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 1435: invalid continuation byte

the character is the È letter. What have I to do to read correctly the ini file?

This is the dump of the char giving the problem:

```
000590 2D 70 6C 61 79 65 72 73 20 3D 20 C8 20 73 74 61 
0005A0 74 6F 20 72 61 67 67 69 75 6E 74 6F 20 69 6C 20
```

the problem is on 00059B (C8) that is: È

This is the ini file:

```
[SETUP]
file-name = lva-1600x900.png
bg-color = white
bg-startup = startup-janas.png
bye-image = good-bye.png
box-count = 63
box-points-count = 4
width = 1600
height = 900
pawns = dea-64.png, sardus-64.png, luna-64.png, spirale-64.png, stella-64.png, toro-64.png
dies = die1.png, die2.png, die3.png, die4.png, die5.png, die6.png
file-domande = domande.ini
window-ico = janas.ico
testing = 0
debug = OFF
unit-test = 0

[CDIALOGS]
posx = 0
posy = 0
posxy = +533+332

[CASKDIALOG]
icon = janas.ico
image = question.png
bg-color = #D5BF99
bg-image = None
btn-text-yes = SI
btn-text-no = NO

[CERRORDIALOG]
icon = janas.ico
image = error.png
bg-color = #D5BF99
bg-image = None
btn-text = CONFERMO

[CINFODIALOG]
icon = janas.ico
image = info.png
bg-color = #D5BF99
bg-image = None
btn-text = CONFERMO

[CINFOMSG]
icon = janas.ico
image = ../data/info.png
bg-color = #D5BF99
bg-image = None

[CWARNINGDIALOG]
icon = janas.ico
image = warning.png
bg-color = #D5BF99
bg-image = None
btn-text = CONFERMO

[CFORMDICE]
icon = janas.ico
btn-text = LANCIA I DADI
title = LANCIO DEI DADI
posxy = +0+0

[CFORMNEWPLAYER]
icon = janas.ico
name = Nome
pawn = Pedina
btn-confirm = Conferma
btn-cancel = Termina
btn-ok = OK
title-err = Errore
title-warning = Attenzione
text-err-name = Non hai inserito il tuo nome
text-err-img = Non hai selezionato un'immagine
text-max-players = È stato raggiunto il numero massimo di giocatori
title-question = Domanda
text-question = Hai finito di inserire i giocatori?
posxy = +492+116

[CFORMQUIZ]
bg-image = None
icon = janas.ico
text = Scegli una risposta e poi premi su Invio
text-one = Guarda attentamente l'immagine, sai dirmi di cosa si tratta...
question-icon = questionmark-64.png
match-sound = card-match.wav
wrong-sound = card-nomatch.mp3
match-text = Risposta esatta
wrong-text = Risposta sbagliata, accumuli 30 penalità
match-img = greenlight-64.png
wrong-img = redlight-64.png
selected-img = selected-32.png
unselected-img = unselected-32.png

[CGUIINTF]
play-or-exit-title = Gioco delle Janas
play-or-exit-text = Vuoi giocare?
same-players = Stessi giocatori?
add-players = Nuovo giocatore
game-turn-text = È il turno di
game-turn-title = TURNO DI GIOCO
game-end-text = Il vincitore è:
game-end-title = Info
game-end-btn-text = OK

[CMESSAGEDIALOG]
icon = janas.ico
bg-color = #D5BF99
bg-image = None

[CMESSAGEWIN]
icon = janas.ico
bg-color = #D5BF99
bg-image = None

[CTURNFORM]
icon = janas.ico
penalty = Penalità:
bg-color = #D5BF99
bg-image = None

[GAMEACTIONS]
goose-title = Casa della Jana
goose-text = Ripeti il movimento
bridge-title = 6 - Casa del ponte
bridge-text = Ripeti il movimento
inn-title = 19 - Casa della locanda
inn-text = Resti nella locanda 3 turni di gioco
drain-title = 31 - Casa del pozzo
drain-text = Resti nel pozzo fino all'arrivo di un'altra pedina
labyrynth-title = 42 - Casa del labirinto
labyrynth-text = Retrocedi alla casa 33.
jail-title = 52 - Casa della prigione
jail-text = Resti in prigione fino all'arrivo di un'altra pedina.
skeleton-title = 58 - Casa dello scheletro
skeleton-text = Paghi la posta e ritorni alla casella 1.
quiz-header = Quiz
quiz-title = Casa del quiz
quiz-text-ok = Risposta esatta: ripeti il movimento

[GAMEICONS]
goose-icon = jana-ico.png
bridge-icon = bridge-ico.png
inn-icon = inn-ico.png
drain-icon = drain-ico.png
labyrynth-icon = labyrynth-ico.png
jail-icon = jail-ico.png
skeleton-icon = skeleton-ico.png

[BOX-START]
point-1 = 10,720
point-2 = 350,720
point-3 = 350,800
point-4 = 10,800

[BOX-1]
point-1 = 398,729
point-2 = 401,845
point-3 = 479,836
point-4 = 488,741

[BOX-2]
point-1 = 505,745
point-2 = 504,834
point-3 = 580,835
point-4 = 587,746

[BOX-3]
point-1 = 604,742
point-2 = 597,837
point-3 = 672,840
point-4 = 672,738

[BOX-4]
point-1 = 695,746
point-2 = 696,842
point-3 = 771,840
point-4 = 770,746

[BOX-5]
point-1 = 793,747
point-2 = 787,842
point-3 = 880,842
point-4 = 883,745

[BOX-6]
point-1 = 897,744
point-2 = 901,843
point-3 = 987,842
point-4 = 983,743

[BOX-7]
point-1 = 1004,744
point-2 = 1005,842
point-3 = 1096,841
point-4 = 1069,742

[BOX-8]
point-1 = 1085,738
point-2 = 1113,842
point-3 = 1200,831
point-4 = 1142,731

[BOX-9]
point-1 = 1218,694
point-2 = 1158,725
point-3 = 1226,825
point-4 = 1321,787

[BOX-10]
point-1 = 1283,649
point-2 = 1244,687
point-3 = 1342,772
point-4 = 1395,727

[BOX-11]
point-1 = 1327,593
point-2 = 1298,632
point-3 = 1415,709
point-4 = 1463,653

[BOX-12]
point-1 = 1363,537
point-2 = 1340,582
point-3 = 1469,638
point-4 = 1504,570

[BOX-13]
point-1 = 1369,486
point-2 = 1365,521
point-3 = 1513,558
point-4 = 1525,493

[BOX-14]
point-1 = 1364,410
point-2 = 1370,466
point-3 = 1535,480
point-4 = 1523,394

[BOX-15]
point-1 = 1349,360
point-2 = 1364,396
point-3 = 1519,372
point-4 = 1492,311

[BOX-16]
point-1 = 1314,301
point-2 = 1338,341
point-3 = 1488,300
point-4 = 1432,228

[BOX-17]
point-1 = 1270,249
point-2 = 1305,289
point-3 = 1414,217
point-4 = 1348,169

[BOX-18]
point-1 = 1243,107
point-2 = 1176,194
point-3 = 1250,244
point-4 = 1327,150

[BOX-19]
point-1 = 1090,61
point-2 = 1074,162
point-3 = 1157,188
point-4 = 1229,95

[BOX-20]
point-1 = 993,61
point-2 = 994,160
point-3 = 1065,165
point-4 = 1071,56

[BOX-21]
point-1 = 896,60
point-2 = 899,161
point-3 = 976,161
point-4 = 978,61

[BOX-22]
point-1 = 808,65
point-2 = 803,164
point-3 = 882,158
point-4 = 889,59

[BOX-23]
point-1 = 703,53
point-2 = 702,160
point-3 = 788,161
point-4 = 790,58

[BOX-24]
point-1 = 621,51
point-2 = 620,162
point-3 = 688,159
point-4 = 688,57

[BOX-25]
point-1 = 526,56
point-2 = 524,156
point-3 = 603,156
point-4 = 607,55

[BOX-26]
point-1 = 412,58
point-2 = 441,162
point-3 = 506,158
point-4 = 504,51

[BOX-27]
point-1 = 292,94
point-2 = 375,193
point-3 = 431,168
point-4 = 396,63

[BOX-28]
point-1 = 279,101
point-2 = 202,142
point-3 = 325,229
point-4 = 362,198

[BOX-29]
point-1 = 196,154
point-2 = 144,206
point-3 = 285,267
point-4 = 315,233

[BOX-30]
point-1 = 137,217
point-2 = 99,275
point-3 = 258,315
point-4 = 275,279

[BOX-31]
point-1 = 97,287
point-2 = 79,393
point-3 = 245,387
point-4 = 249,326

[BOX-32]
point-1 = 77,408
point-2 = 107,506
point-3 = 257,459
point-4 = 242,397

[BOX-33]
point-1 = 114,515
point-2 = 150,567
point-3 = 286,500
point-4 = 263,469

[BOX-34]
point-1 = 158,582
point-2 = 206,629
point-3 = 322,547
point-4 = 290,510

[BOX-35]
point-1 = 220,637
point-2 = 291,674
point-3 = 369,573
point-4 = 328,554

[BOX-36]
point-1 = 381,579
point-2 = 307,682
point-3 = 404,695
point-4 = 440,605

[BOX-37]
point-1 = 450,603
point-2 = 408,712
point-3 = 482,724
point-4 = 504,622

[BOX-38]
point-1 = 518,625
point-2 = 502,726
point-3 = 585,726
point-4 = 590,626

[BOX-39]
point-1 = 607,628
point-2 = 603,727
point-3 = 673,730
point-4 = 677,626

[BOX-40]
point-1 = 692,625
point-2 = 687,723
point-3 = 772,726
point-4 = 778,629

[BOX-41]
point-1 = 792,627
point-2 = 786,723
point-3 = 881,721
point-4 = 887,628

[BOX-42]
point-1 = 906,626
point-2 = 898,729
point-3 = 999,724
point-4 = 999,627

[BOX-43]
point-1 = 1016,627
point-2 = 1012,725
point-3 = 1096,719
point-4 = 1054,616

[BOX-44]
point-1 = 1108,591
point-2 = 1070,616
point-3 = 1115,716
point-4 = 1208,682

[BOX-45]
point-1 = 1179,537
point-2 = 1130,583
point-3 = 1224,672
point-4 = 1311,590

[BOX-46]
point-1 = 1200,471
point-2 = 1186,518
point-3 = 1320,573
point-4 = 1352,477

[BOX-47]
point-1 = 1190,409
point-2 = 1199,457
point-3 = 1350,460
point-4 = 1338,359

[BOX-48]
point-1 = 1158,356
point-2 = 1185,393
point-3 = 1325,350
point-4 = 1274,285

[BOX-49]
point-1 = 1164,214
point-2 = 1096,308
point-3 = 1146,348
point-4 = 1263,277

[BOX-50]
point-1 = 1012,179
point-2 = 993,279
point-3 = 1080,305
point-4 = 1140,204

[BOX-51]
point-1 = 896,181
point-2 = 902,287
point-3 = 973,284
point-4 = 1001,181

[BOX-52]
point-1 = 793,184
point-2 = 799,284
point-3 = 877,285
point-4 = 880,181

[BOX-53]
point-1 = 710,180
point-2 = 715,288
point-3 = 785,283
point-4 = 785,180

[BOX-54]
point-1 = 619,177
point-2 = 614,285
point-3 = 702,287
point-4 = 700,178

[BOX-55]
point-1 = 496,173
point-2 = 565,291
point-3 = 606,284
point-4 = 604,178

[BOX-56]
point-1 = 483,178
point-2 = 402,199
point-3 = 510,312
point-4 = 554,295

[BOX-57]
point-1 = 387,203
point-2 = 317,256
point-3 = 459,343
point-4 = 495,317

[BOX-58]
point-1 = 307,267
point-2 = 266,340
point-3 = 420,397
point-4 = 452,355

[BOX-59]
point-1 = 261,358
point-2 = 271,453
point-3 = 417,453
point-4 = 418,415

[BOX-60]
point-1 = 279,467
point-2 = 326,531
point-3 = 426,495
point-4 = 414,463

[BOX-61]
point-1 = 338,540
point-2 = 401,572
point-3 = 446,543
point-4 = 427,506

[BOX-62]
point-1 = 451,549
point-2 = 405,577
point-3 = 522,614
point-4 = 546,585

[BOX-63]
point-1 = 452,378
point-2 = 442,501
point-3 = 597,507
point-4 = 607,301

[FORMMODAL]
posxy = +0+0

[CASADELQUIZ]
posxy = +0+0

[QUIZ]
posxy = +450+53

[LANCIODEIDADI]
posxy = +0+0
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the hex dump of the piece of the file which fails (containing the `È`)?  You can obtain a hex dump on Linux or Mac with `xxd`, or on Windows PowerShell with `Format-Hex`.  Also, say what OS you're using.

Comment: The o.s. in Windows(7..10) The hex dump reveals that the character is correct (0xc8) LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH GRAVE

Comment: If you want help you really need to show us that hex dump of this character and the surrounding ones so we can try it on our own.  Also, paste your code into the question.

Comment: I can add the origina file because the problem is on 1453 character and then using notepad++ you can verify that it is the first occurrence of a char that is not present in the ASCII table. After that there are more.

Comment: Use PowerShell `Format-Hex` to dump the file as hex and paste the line with the problem plus the line before it.

Comment: are you able to fin the char in 1453 position? I already did... 0xC8 that is È there is nothing non ASCII before. The point is that it is a UTF-8 file and it is correctly displayed and encoded in the file. In my opinion the problem is how read the file in Python and what is the correct decoder. Is 'utf-8' right? Or not?

Comment: Well it worked fine on my machine (Mac OS).  Here's the hex dump with the `È`: `7475 726e 2d74 6578 7420 3d20 c388 2069  turn-text = .. i` - as you can see it is not `c8` on my machine, rather it is `c388`.  I think your file may not be valid UTF-8.

Comment: Well, I wrote the file and saved in utf-8, at least PyDev now is set to write in in UTF-8 and then I checked the format using a hex editor and seems that when I read the file using ConfigParser it rewrites the file in unicode format.